# Is it possible to add a function to a loop in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am still pretty new to Ruby and coding in general and I have been struggling at this particular task for a while a now.
I just wanted to know how to add a function in Ruby within a loop. For example:

```
def main()
name=read_string("What is your name? ")
if name=="Tom"
    puts "an awesome name"
else
    def print_silly_name(name)
        i=0
        puts name + " is a #{i}"+"name!"
        while i<60
            loop do puts " silly"
                i=i+1
            end
```

The output should have the word "silly" printed 60 times but I am not sure how to call the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You first *define* your method, e.g.:

```
def print_silly_name(name)
  print "#{name} is a"
  60.times { print " silly" }
  puts " name!"
end
```

And then you *call* your method:

```
def main
  name = read_string("What is your name?")

  if name == "Tom"
    puts "an awesome name"
  else
    print_silly_name(name)
  end
end
```

Example output:

> What is your name?
>
> *Bob*
>
> Bob is a silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly silly name!

Answer (score 1):

You must delare the method outside of `main()`:

```
def print_silly_name(name)
  i=0
  while (i<60)
      puts name + " is a #{i}"+"name!"
      i+=1
  end
end
```

and than just call it in your `.rb` file:

```
print_silly_name('Josh')
```

Comment: Declaring the method outside of `main` is correct, but your method won't run – Ruby doesn't have a `++` postfix increment operator.